# How to interpret a qq plot of uniform distribution whose slope is greater than 1

Tags: r, uniform-distribution, qq-plot

I am trying to interpret a qq plot of a uniform distribution in R where the plot is as shown in the image. The qq lines are a kind of straight but the slope of these lines way greater than the 45 degree line. How do I interpret this plot?[image]

Comment: These are *empirical cumulative distribution function* (ECDF) plots turned sideways.